# generate normal distribution with exactly N elements in Y bins

Tags: r, distribution, normal-distribution, binning

I'll probably want to hit myself over the head for not getting this:

How do I generate a vector with the expected *height* of a normal distribution over *Y* bins (`nbins` in the below), of exactly *N* elements.

Like so, in the below picture:

- Y or `nbins` = 15
- N or `nstat` = 77
- ... should return something like: c(1,1,2,4, ...)

[image: example q sort]

I know I could draw `rnorm(77)`, but that'll never be *exactly* normal, and looping over 10.000 iterations or so seems overkill.

So I tried using `qnorm` for that purpose, but I have a hunch that:

1. sth is wrong with the below code
2. there has to be an easier, more elegant way

Here is what I got:

```
nbins <- 15
nstat <- 77

item.pos <- qnorm( # to the left of which value lies...
  1:(nstat) / (nstat+1)# ... the n-statement?
  # using nstat + 1 because we want midpoints, not cutoffs for later
)

bins <- cut(
  x = item.pos,
  breaks = nbins,
  ordered_result = TRUE
)

height <- summary(bins)
height <- as.numeric(bins)
```

Comment: Dou you want a standard normal distribution? Looking at the plot I assume not. Can you give the parameters please?

Comment: thanks @Rstudent
I *do* want a standard normal distribution.
The plot is off, I hacked it together by hand.
Hence the need for a proper R function :).

Comment: Calculate the percentiles from your normal distribution corresponding to the range for each bin, multiply each percentile by N to get the expected number in that bin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your range of data is from `-2:2` with `15` intervals and the sample size is `77` I would suggest the following to get the expected heights of the 15 intervals:

```
rn <- dnorm(seq(-2,2, length = 15))/sum(dnorm(seq(-2,2, length = 15)))*77
 [1] 1.226486 2.084993 3.266586 4.716619 6.276462 7.697443 8.700123 9.062576 8.700123 7.697443
[11] 6.276462 4.716619 3.266586 2.084993 1.226486
```

The barplot of this looks like:

```
barplot(height = rn, names.arg = round(seq(-2, 2, length = 15), 2))
```

[image]

So, in your sample of `77` you would get the first value of the sequence in `1.226486`, the second value in `2.084993` cases, etc. Its difficult to generate a vector as you described at the beginning, because the  sequence above does not consist of integers.

Comment: thanks @RStudent, I'm being really dense today.
Since I need integers eventually, should I then just *round* the resulting vector?

Comment: Look at the graph. If you round them you get numbers which are either `-2`, `-1`, `0`, `1` or `2`. So, you only get four numbers.

Comment: In this example, the sum of the expected heights comes out to 260.9996 instead of 77.  You need to normalize the probabilities first.  probs = dnorm(seq(-2, 2, length = 15));
heights = probs/sum(probs) * 77

Comment: great @RStudent.
Slight misunderstanding: I meant rounding the resulting vector `rn`, because I need it to be integers.
Of course with rounding, the resulting length of `rn` is sometimes not *exactly* as specified in `nstat` (try 55, max.bin 6, for example).

That's just something I'll have to live with, right?

Comment: one more small question @Rstudent: you hard-coded `-2, 2` as ranges.
Since my `nstat` will vary widely (from, say 20 to 100), I want this range to vary with nstat, so I thought of setting it to `range <- qnorm(1/nstat)` so that the range always begins where we can expect 1/n to the left of that cutoff point.
Does that make sense?

Comment: Of course you can round them but as you say they will not be exact anymore. Tha range `-2:2` is set arbitrarily. Your suggested range of `-qnorm(1/nstat):qnorm(1/nstat)` seems to me reasonable, because with increasing sample size the small probabilities on the two edges of the distribution have significant values after multiplication with `nstat`.